# How to migrate flutter project to androidx

Tags: android, dart, flutter

How to migrate existing flutter project to Android X ? Are there any pro and cons?

Comment: you can't migrate from flutter to Android X. Android X is just a library for Android.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would require to migrate to Android X if you intend to use features that have breaking changes for the latest library. I personally faced this problem [cloud_firestore 0.9.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore#090) as the change log says, it required a migration to Android X.

Your Android app is in the `android` directory of the project. First open the `android` directory with `Android Studio 3.2+`. Then **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX**. After that also add these to the `gradle.properties` file in the `android` directory

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 5):

In your IDE menu, go to `Refactor` and use `Migrate to AndroidX...`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I did the same mentioned what has been mentioned by the last two answers. (Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX ...) but it didn't help really. I still got the error by flutter that it's not a AndroidX project.

**I fixed it** by adding;

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

to 
android/gradle.properties

Note, there are one in root and the other in android-directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I can not see the ***gradle.properties*** file under the android path. So, create new ***gradle.properties*** and adding the following lines of code inside it has solved the problem

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

The next thing I do is adding the following androidx enabler code to the ***pubspec.yaml*** file

module:
androidx: true

Note: It is recommended to perform the clean and get operations before and after making the changes to your project.

Regards.