# adding firebase to flutter project and getting FAILURE: Build failed with an exception error

Tags: flutter

for [this flutter library][1] as `barcode scanner` i should to adding `firebase` to project, but after doing that i get this error and i cant fix that yet

> Launching lib\main.dart on WAS LX1A in debug mode... Initializing
>   gradle... Resolving dependencies...
>   * Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process "E:\Projects\Flutter\barcode_scanner\android\gradlew.bat" exited
>   abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'E:\Projects\Flutter\barcode_scanner\android\app\build.gradle' line:
>     14
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
>   > ASCII
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6s   Command:
>   E:\Projects\Flutter\barcode_scanner\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
>
> Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the
>   android/ folder.

line 14 is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

I'm not sure whats problem and this is my implementation about that

`pabspec.yaml` content:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  ...
...
```

`android/build.gradle` content:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle` content:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "barcodescanner.pishguy.barcode_scanner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

running `flutter` command:

```
E:\Projects\Flutter\barcode_scanner>flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in barcode_scanner...                     2.7s


  [1]: https://github.com/facundomedica/fast_qr_reader_view
```

Comment: Does anyone have a current solution, as the current version for google-services is 4.3.2?

Answer (score 30):

There is problem with **'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'.**
Switch it to **'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'**, it's worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Yes!. setting : classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' in build.gradle works!

Answer (score 6):

This is my same exact problem; I managed to solve this problem on my end.

Here is the changes I had made on my code:

On AppName/Android/gradle/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50' //had to changed it previously 1.2.71
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1' //had to changed previously 3.2.1
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}
```

then on AppName/Android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties I had just changed this line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip //it was peviously gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

after all those changes my app works.

Comment: what is the Gradle version in gradle-wrapper-properties?

Comment: This worked for me for `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are some [breaking changes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) in the latest versions of the firebase libraries. I faced the same problem but after [migrating to AndriodX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967616/how-to-migrate-flutter-project-to-androidx/54967706#54967706) everything was was working.

Answer (score 1):

if this **'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'.
Switch it to 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'** doesn't work or brings other errors like mine did.......add this

```
subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

to the android/build.gradle

so your code will be

```
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }

    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }

                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please share what was the issue I am in same problem. thanks in advance

Comment: follow all the solutions here,if they don't work add mine