# Why my pubspec.yaml file not working and contain a class R iam not writing this class?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and I have created an app with firestore the problem is my pubspec.yaml file not working

I tried to migrate to androidx[This screenshot of my pubspec.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFNJ.jpg)

Comment: Erm.. Where did you get shown to put classes inside your pubspec.yaml file??

Comment: I am not sure what was put in your pubsec.yaml file. Can you please share the source that told you how to migrate to androidX that way we can assist you better? It is likely what you put in the pubsec.yaml (a package manager file) was meant to be placed in another file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to know what you should put in pubspec.yaml and how to migrate to AndroidX.

In order to migrate to androidX, please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967616/how-to-migrate-flutter-project-to-androidx)

For pubspec.yaml, you should put Flutter plugin in it.
[image]

Hope it helps!