# Unable to build apk, firebase_admob making Error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to build apk but firebase admob is making problem, if I run without `firebase_admob` then apk works perfectly and built without any error how to resolve that issue?

I am getting this error :

> Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources' in this case.

I am using `firebase_admob: ^0.5.2` this version of it I even try some latest versions but the problem is still there.

```
C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1>flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              1.3s
Resolving dependencies...                                           4.7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':firebase_admob:verifyReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed

  C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:304: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not foun
d.

  C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports1\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:305: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.





* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 3m 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          190.9s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hello. You probably need to migrate your app to AndroidX. You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967616/how-to-migrate-flutter-project-to-androidx/54967706#54967706) answer if it helps. The answer is mine, this probably is a shameless plug.

Comment: No usage found in the project. by following that answer.

Comment: Do you have the latest build of `firebase_admob`?

Comment: `firebase_admob 0.9.0+7` yes I do apply different versions to build apk but failed.

Comment: Go to `build.gradle` in android folder. What is the compile sdk version? Is it 28?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28
 minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: I am sorry. This is something I may not be able to help. One last try might be to lower the library version. Like try admob version 0.8.0 or 0.7.0

Comment: I did all these tricks but none of these works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing similar error.  but I would like to suggest you to make appbundle which is the best option to upload app. Run `flutter build appbundle` sign it with google play store signing enrollment and upload. I resolve it with this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you haven't migrated your project to `AndroidX`, all you need to do is, in your IDE use

```
Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX
```

After this

```
File > Invalidate Caches and Restart
```

Comment: No usage found in the project by applying this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the dependencies in Android/app/build.gradle?

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Which version of the ad_mob package are you using? Are you using AndroidX on your app?

Comment: Follow the instruction on migrating your app to AndroidX [https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#for-plugin-maintainers-migrating-a-flutter-plugin-to-androidx]

Comment: @JoãoSoares  I am using firebase_admob: ^0.5.2.  How do I know I am using AndroidX on myapp?? I am new on flutter thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need to add this on build.gradle. When you import the library in pubspec yaml these libraries are added by the library modules.

Comment: @ShababbKarim it seems everything ok in my project but why the error is still there If I remove ' firebase_admob' from whole project apk build successfully but  firebase_admob is making a problem.