# Show app bar or a flat button on screen tap

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a video player and have a custom button to go back. I want to show that button on screen tap and hide after 1 or 2 second. that can be a transparent app bar that show on screen tap and hide and that app bar contain a custom button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: YourPage()));

class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourPageState createState() => _YourPageState();
}

class _YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  bool _showControls = false; // set it to false initially

  _showAndHideControls() {
    // show controls the moment user tapped on screen
    setState(() => _showControls = true);

    // after 2 seconds, hide the controls
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() => _showControls = false);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _showControls ? AppBar(title: Text("AppBar")) : null,
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Click me"),
          onPressed: _showAndHideControls,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks cops this is what I want. In case I have video player and I want to tap on the screen of video player to open this appbar which contains only a back button ?

Comment: @Developer You can handle the logic inside WillPopScope. I am not on computer so can't help you much as of now.

Comment: let me give u a scenario I have a full-screen video player and have a back button on the left top of my screen I want to hide the button initially when user tap on the screen that button should appear for 2 seconds and then disappear. that all that I need to do. I have button and every thing working perfectly but I need to hide that button initially and show on-screen tap.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you were able to create a `GestureDetector` or something like that which would show you the `AppBar` containing back button.

All you need to do after that is:

```
bool _showControls = false;

_showAndHideControls() {
  setState(() {
    _showControls = true; // show controls the moment user tapped on screen
  });

  Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    setState(() {
      _showControls = false; // after 2 seconds, hide the controls 
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I can but since you didn't share any code, I am not sure how can I show you where to place this code.

Comment: cops,  in the very basic app you can show the app bar by tapping the screen. later I will implement it to code.

Comment: Currently, I am not in front of a computer, so I'll show when I get to it.

Comment: can you help me to get rid off this problem please here is the question I put on this platform But I did not get answered (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115011/unable-to-build-apk-firebase-admob-making-error)
I am just messed up due to this

Comment: I have added a simple answer to show you. Check it out.